# How to fetch connections' interests using linkedIn Javascript api?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch the interests of people who are returned after a PeopleSearch call. As I understand it, to read the user's interests, I need to the r_fullprofile permission. Does this mean that I can never retrieve the interests of my user's connections, since my app is authenticated only by my user and not by his connections?

What I am trying to do is match users with people in their network who have similar interests. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can retrieve those, but you will need to use the `r_network` scope instead, which will give you access to the connections list and people search , as defined on [granting permissions documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting) .

After that, you should use the [intestests field selector](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields) inside your search calls, in order to receive that field in your searches, [as outlined in the developer documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/field-selectors)

The data you receive via the API is the same data the user can see on the Linkedin website. So your best bet would be to restrict your search to 1st, 2nd and 3rd degree connections.

Comment: Using the r_network will only give me access to the user's connections (the person who has authenticated my app). It will not give me the interests of those returned connections (even if they are first degree).

Comment: What does this call return? `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,interests))?keywords=anything&count=10&start=0`

Comment: since I am using JSAPI, I rewrote that call like this:

[code]IN.API.PeopleSearch()
.fields("firstName", "lastName", "interests")
.params({"sort":"distance", "count":5})
.result(function(peopleSearch){
    console.log(peopleSearch);
})
.error(displayErrors);[/code]

The call only returned firstName and lastName. No interest fields, even though the results returned are first degree.

Comment: Your best bet would be to ask on the linkedin forums. Their employees are always on the forums, so you would get an official answer if this could be done or not.